# React Native - iOS release build failure

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, archive

Archive is failed in release build with the following error but it is not an issue for debug build

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

    CompileC .../_appcircle_temp/appcircle_export_archive/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Flipper-Folly.build/Objects-normal/armv7/VirtualEventBase.o .../_appcircle_temp/Repository/ios/Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/io/async/VirtualEventBase.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

**PodFile**

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.1' })
  pre_install do |installer|
    $RNMBGL.pre_install(installer)
  end
  post_install do |installer|
    $RNMBGL.post_install(installer)
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    fix_deployment_target(installer)
  end
end

def fix_deployment_target(installer)
  return if !installer
  project = installer.pods_project
  project_deployment_target = project.build_configurations.first.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']

  puts "Make sure all pods deployment target is #{project_deployment_target.green}"
  project.targets.each do |target|
    puts "  #{target.name}".blue
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      old_target = config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']
      new_target = project_deployment_target
      next if old_target == new_target
      puts "    #{config.name}: #{old_target.yellow} -> #{new_target.green}"
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = new_target
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tried deleting the `Pods` folder and `Podfile.lock` file, then running `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`?

Answer (score 0):

If in your error message you get something with DerivedData it is always a good idea to delete the complete subfolder in DerivedData dedicated to your app.

After that I would do `pod install` and Clean in Xcode and retry to build the app.